# Where can I find the source code for the apt package manager?

Tags: apt, package-management, source-code

I would like to modify some functionalities in the `apt-get` package manager, but I can only find the `apt-get` binaries.

Where is the source code for the package manager?

Comment: Here:https://github.com/Debian/apt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `deb-src` type repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
```

Replace `trusty` with the codename of the release you are using. You can find the codename by:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Now sync the local package lists with remote repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can download the source package of `apt` in the current directory:

```
apt-get source apt
```

From the extracted directory, the file you are looking for is:

```
cmdline/apt-get.cc
```

Comment: Right as I was writing the answer, you beat me to it.  =)

Comment: @Terrance Happens to most of us ;)

Comment: Well, he who as the fastest fingers will win!  ;)